# how field relations works in django

Tags: django-models

I've been shattering my head to get my head around the realtion fields in django.

I have explored the internet for explanations about relations in django.
I'm new to django and conversant with SQL,I know how things work in SQL but I could'nt make anything  of what django does.

I searched on stackoverflow there were few answers which didnt really help me and therefore I had to ask for bit more explanation.
since records in django are objects what does a foreign key attribute in django model hold?.does it hold a reference to target model(in SQL it holds the PK of referenced relation record).what are 'reverse relations and all those stuff'.

how do things work in django??.what is django's approach.provide me with some good articulation.I kindly urge!
how does django differs from SQL in this aspect?

Answer (score 0):

Why not see for yourself?

In, say, employees/models.py:

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Employee(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager)
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And then you can view the SQL that this model would generate by running:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations employees
Migrations for 'employees':
0001_initial.py:
- Create model Employee
- Create model Manager
- Add field manager to employee

$ ./manage.py sqlmigrate employees 0001_initial
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "employees_employee" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(40) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE "employees_manager" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(40) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE "employees_employee__new" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(40) NOT NULL, "manager_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "employees_manager" ("id"));
INSERT INTO "employees_employee__new" ("manager_id", "id", "name") SELECT NULL, "id", "name" FROM "employees_employee";
DROP TABLE "employees_employee";
ALTER TABLE "employees_employee__new" RENAME TO "employees_employee";
CREATE INDEX "employees_employee_8784215c" ON "employees_employee" ("manager_id");
```

Furthermore if you're wondering how a specific query might work, a useful tool is the "query" attribute:

```
>>> print(Employee.objects.all().query)
SELECT "employees_employee"."id", "employees_employee"."manager_id", "employees_employee"."name" FROM "employees_employee"
```

and don't forget that the [source code of Django](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db) is readily available for perusal, if you ever really want to explore the nitty-gritty details.